# Не могу найти ошибку в формуле. Код Java, он на c# тоже работает(если переделать ввод и вывод)

Tags: java, c#, геометрия

я делаю приложение, выводящее спираль(в целях образования). Но спираль выводится с редкими придатками, в местах отклоняющихся на на количество градусов кратное 90 от старта.[image: все и так видно]

часть кода в которой может быть ошибка:

```
        //формула для интервала между точками: р/м точки между которыми ищем интервал как окружность
        //1)находим кол-во точек по формуле 2Pr
        //2)делим 360 на полученное число
        interval = (double)(360.0 / (double)(Math.PI * (Wid / 2 * ((howManyCircles * 360 - deg ) /         
        (howManyCircles * 360))) * 2));

        // формула позиций: р/м точку которую рисуем как прямоугольный треугольник
        //1) сделаем допущение, что позиция по X и позиция по Y это катеты,
        // следовательно расстояние до точки это гипотенуза.
        //2) нам известен угол(т.к. он является счетчиком(переменная deg))и гипотенуза по формуле:
        // (Wid / 2 * ((howManyCircles * 360 - deg + 1) / (howManyCircles * 360)))
        // следовательно находим катеты: (Х)косинус угла * на гипотенузу,(Y)косинус(угла - 90) * на         
        гипотенузу
        PosX = (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(deg)) * (Wid / 2 * ((howManyCircles * 360 - deg ) / 
        (howManyCircles * 360))));
        PosY = (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 - deg)) * (Wid / 2 * ((howManyCircles * 360 - deg ) / 
        (howManyCircles * 360))) / 2.25);
```

P.S. всё перевожу в double Т.К. устал думать, что надо переводить, а что не надо.

P.P.S если кому надо, вот весь код мэйна:

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input Width :");
        int Wid = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("input how many circles :");
        double howManyCircles = in.nextDouble();
        double interval;
        int[][] doubleArray = new int[Wid][Wid];
        int PosX = 0;
        int PosY = 0;
        for (double deg = 1; deg < howManyCircles * 360; deg += interval){
            interval = (double)(360.0 / (double)(Math.PI * (Wid / 2 * ((howManyCircles * 360 - deg ) / 
            (howManyCircles * 360))) * 2));
            PosX = (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(deg)) * (Wid / 2 * ((howManyCircles * 360 - deg ) / 
            (howManyCircles * 360))));
            PosY = (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 - deg)) * (Wid / 2 * ((howManyCircles * 360 - deg ) / 
            (howManyCircles * 360))) / 2.25);
            doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2][PosY + Wid / 2] = 1;
        }
        for (int Y = 0; Y < Wid; Y++){
            for (int X = 0; X < Wid; X++){
                if (doubleArray[Wid - 1 - X][Wid - 1 - Y] == 1){
                    System.out.print("#");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Смотрю на математику- вроде все правильно (надеюсь, ничего не упустил). Смотрю на спираль - вроде тоже нормально... Какие придатки Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Нда.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/1crp9.png что-то не выходит нормально

Comment: Нда.... тут заметно ,что что-то "не так" :)

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю проблемы с java кодом, то "придатки" - это когда из-за ошибки округления сразу в двух местах прорисовывается "линия" из # и хочет от таких удвоенных "ступенек" избавиться.

Comment: Я делал методом подбора шага с отрубанием соседних клеток, если соседняя клетка только одна, но у меня ширина "пикселя" - 2 знакоместа. У вас все сложнее, но вдруг поможет. ([пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1180357/373567))

Comment: Здравствуйте, я увеличил ширину пикселя по вашему примеру. Что решило проблему. Думаю, вам стоит, ответить таким образом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никакой ошибки не было, Данные "придатки" появлялись в результате корявого округления. Я просто увеличил ширину пикселя, и оно просто перестало себя проявлять. Всем спасибо за участие.

Чтоб модераторы не ворчали, придётся опубликовать ещё и код.
Вот так теперь выглядит отрисовка:

```cs
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2][PosY + Wid / 2] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 1][PosY + Wid / 2] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 2][PosY + Wid / 2] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 3][PosY + Wid / 2] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 4][PosY + Wid / 2] = 1;
        
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2][PosY + Wid / 2 + 1] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 1][PosY + Wid / 2 + 1] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 2][PosY + Wid / 2 + 1] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 3][PosY + Wid / 2 + 1] = 1;
        doubleArray[PosX + Wid / 2 + 4][PosY + Wid / 2 + 1] = 1;
```

Вот так выглядит объявление массива:

```
        int[][] doubleArray = new int[Wid + 4][Wid + 4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double interval;
        int PosX;
        int PosY;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Width: ");
        int Wid = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input Number of Curves: ");
        int numberOfCurves = in.nextInt();
        double a = (numberOfCurves * 360);

        char[][] charArray = new char[Wid][Wid];
        for (double deg = 1; deg < a; deg += interval) {
            double b = (numberOfCurves * 360 - deg) / a;
            double c = (Wid / 2) * b;
            interval = (360.0 / (Math.PI * c));
            PosX = (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(deg)) * c);
            PosY = (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 - deg)) * c / 2.25);
            charArray[PosX + Wid / 2][PosY + Wid / 2] = '#';
        }
        for (int Y = 0; Y < Wid; Y++) {
            for (int X = 0; X < Wid; X++) {
                System.out.print(charArray[Wid - 1 - X][Wid - 1 - Y]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        in.close();
    }
```