# Смена цвета в случайных позициях в C#

Tags: c#, консоль, текст, вывод, цвета

Недавно у меня появилось новогоднее настроение (мда в начале декабря), надеюсь оно как обычно не пропадёт под конец года. Мне как раз нечего было разрабатывать и писать, я решил сделать себе программистский Новый Год на C#. Я вывел ёлочку под восьмибитную версию Jingle Bells в консоль, вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Media;
using System.Threading;


namespace HappyNewYear
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            // Врубает музыку.
            SoundPlayer jingleBells = new SoundPlayer();
            jingleBells.SoundLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/JingleBells.wav";
            jingleBells.PlayLooping();
            Console.WriteLine("С новым годом!\n");
            StarLayer();
            TreeLayer(3);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
            Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
            Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
            while (true)
            {
                for (byte i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(rand.Next(1, 9), rand.Next(6, 20));
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("0");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(400);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("С новым годом!\n");
                StarLayer();
                TreeLayer(3);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
                Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
                Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Выводит слой ёлочки
        static void TreeLayer(byte amount)
        {
            
            for (byte i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("      0  ");
                Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
                Console.WriteLine("    00000 ");
                Console.WriteLine("   0000000 ");
                Console.WriteLine("  000000000 ");
                Console.WriteLine(" 00000000000 ");
            }
        }

        // Выводит звезду-пизду
        static void StarLayer()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("      0  ");
            Console.WriteLine("    00000  ");
            Console.WriteLine("     000 ");
            Console.WriteLine("    0   0 ");
        }
    }
}
```

В общем я хочу чтобы ёлочка в рандомных местах меняла цвет на рандомный, типа красный, синий, жёлтый и так постоянно, желательно в такт музыке. Я знаю как менять цвет консоли, но вот вышеуказанную задачу просто не потяну.

UPD: По совету Александра Петрова) Я добавил в свой код SetCursorPosition, получилось уже лучше, однако как сделать, чтобы он рандомно ставился только в заполненные поля?[image: Результат:]

Comment: Что именно не понятно?

Comment: как вариант по поробуй это
 Console.ForegroundColor = Random.Next(IEnumerable<Brushes>);

Comment: @Dude36 "Brushes": нельзя использовать статические типы в качестве аргументов типов. "IEnumerable<Brushes>" является тип, который недопустим в данном контексте.

Comment: Задать координаты в консоли: `Console.SetCursorPosition`. Генерировать случайные числа: класс `Random`.

Comment: [Посмотрите это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567). Там если не всё, то большинство из того что вам нужно, есть.

Comment: [Вот еще один пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1180357/373567) работы с консолью.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я приводил выше код. Куда хотя-бы примерно мне ставить SetCursorPosition?

Comment: @n3rovik вы точно заметили 2 ссылки с примерами, где этот `SetCursorPosition` используется? Когда вы вызываете этот метод, консоль переставляет курсор в нужные координаты. Когда вы следом вызываете `Write` или `WriteLine` консоль пишет что-то на месте курсора. Должно быть просто. Далее, почитайте про циклы `for` и `foreach` и `while`. Без них вам будет очень сложно сделать то что вы делаете.

Comment: @aepot так а как сделать чтобы оно рандомно ставило курсор только в заполненные области

Comment: в начале кода `Random rnd = new Random()`, в цикле `Console.SetCursorPosition(rnd.Next(Console.BufferWidth),rnd.Next(Console.BufferHeight))`. Это выставит курсор в рандомную область экрана. Про "заполненные" не понял. Можете эти рандомы запомнить в переменные и использовать как точку отсчета для рисования.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, теперь у меня каша на экране) я имел ввиду заполненные ёлкой области, чтобы он только цвета рандомных элементов ёлки менял.

Comment: Понял. Рандомно будет сложно, просто задайте массив координат и перебирайте его в цикле, записывая символ рандомного цвета. Вам же не нужно много точек, иначе помимо того что в рандомном месте надо будет нарисовать другим цветом, то еще потребуется и стереть потом. `Point[] points = new Point[] { new Point(5, 11), new Point(2, 12) ... }` и так далее. А потом циклом по этому массиву рисуя рандомным цветом. `while (!Console.KeyAvailable) { foreach (Point point in points) { Console.SetCursorPosition(point.X, point.Y); Console.Write(...); } Thread.Sleep(500); } Console.ReadKey(true);`

Comment: @aepot стирать мне это не потребуется, т.к. после каждого рандомного расставления точек ёлочка рисуется в консоли по новой и точки продолжают рисоваться.

Comment: @aepot Плюс я выложил код, а на нём видно что вбивать все корды вручную - это садомазахизм

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.Clear();

    var tree = new string[]
    {
        "     0     ",
        "    000    ",
        "   00000   ",
        "  0000000  ",
        " 000000000 ",
        "00000000000",
        "     0     ",
        "    000    ",
        "   00000   ",
        "  0000000  ",
        " 000000000 ",
        "00000000000",
        "     0     ",
        "    000    ",
        "   00000   ",
        "  0000000  ",
        " 000000000 ",
        "00000000000"
    };

    var random = new Random();

    while (true)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tree.Length; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < tree[y].Length; x++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)random.Next(1, 16);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                Console.Write(tree[y][x]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    };
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо, конечно, но я уже придумал костыль, как работают реальные гирлянды, плюс в твоём коде нельзя менять высоту ёлки хотя у меня если поменять, то мигать будет в других местах

Comment: @n3rovik - покажите свой код, опубликуйте ответ.